# Help to understand proof of a theorem in Local Fields: Jean-Pierre Serre

Tags: local-field

In the part Proof of III, Pg. No. 9, under proof of Proposition 3, Chapter I, it says the following :
Let $x$ be a nonzero element of $m$, and form the ring $A_x$ of fractions of the form $\frac{y}{x^n}$, with $y \in A$, and $ n \geq 0$ arbitrary. Then, Condition (ii) implies that $A_x = K$ ; **indeed if not, $ A_x$ would not be a field**,...
Here, Condition (ii) is the following: $A$ has a unique non-zero prime ideal, where 
$A$ is a Noetherian integral domain.

I understand till before the part in bold, can someone please help me to understand the part in bold? I attach the images of the pages of relevant section below (pardon me for the bad image quality):

[image: Local Feilds, Section 2]

[image: Section 2, Chapter I, Local Fields]

Comment: is it beacuse elements in $m$, the maximal ideal of $A$ are not invertible in $A$, and so they won't be invertible in $A_x$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is a domain with unique nonzero prime ideal. Hence $A_x$ is a domain too, and it's prime ideals are in bijective correspondence with those of $A$ not containing $x$. But this means that the only prime ideal in $A_x$ is the zero ideal, hence it is a field.

Comment: so you are saying that $A_x$ is a field if (ii) is satisfied, regardless of whether $A_x = K$ or not?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, can you please eleaborate?

Comment: I am saying that $A_x$ is a field if the second condition is satisfied and if $x$ is nonzero, yes. The fact that $A_x=K$ holds then follows immediately, since $K$ is the field of fractions of $A$ and therefore of $A_x$ as well.

Comment: Okay, but the author proceeds to prove that $ A_x = K$ by contradiction, and I don't understand why $A_x$ is not a field, if $ A_x \neq K$

Comment: The only subfield of $K$ containing  $A$ is $K$ itself.

Comment: oh okay, is it from the definition of field of fractions?

Comment: thanks, i think i get it now